# Compare proportions from dependent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data

I have two groups of observations, each observation can belong to positive or negative case. For each group I calculate percentage of positive cases.
I want to check whether difference of positives percentage between the groups is statistically significant.

The pitfall is that second group is subset of the first one => **dependent samples** between the groups!!! The case of **independent** samples can be solved by chi-square test, but what can I do with my case ???

Comment: Clearly the population your subset is drawn from is not different from itself. Therefore it only differs from the larger group if it differs from the remainder. (A only differs from A&B combined if it differs from  B).  As a result the dependence is eliminated by comparing the disjoint groups A and not-A. This basic issue is covered in many posts on site across a variety of problem types. (We may need to make a canonical question for this)

Answer (score 1):

Separate the first group into two groups: current second group and another group consists with the obs not in the first group. Compare these two groups by Pearson Chi-square test or Fisher's exact test.

Comparing your current first and second group has no any meaning, because the results depend on the proportion of obs belongs to both groups. Suppose your have 1000 obs, and 990 belong to second group. It will be difficult to detect the difference even the difference between 990 obs and other 10 obs is huge.